# Open local files in ionic iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to open an already present .pdf file on iOS [I can see the files in iBooks]. 
I use Ionic and the [file-opener2 Cordova plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) - I use the latest versions of Cordova and the plugin.

This is the code that works perfectly on Android:

```
$scope.openPDF = function() {
    alert("OK");
    $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
        '/storage/emulated/0/Download/pdf/name.pdf', // Any system location, you CAN'T use your appliaction assets folder           
        'application/pdf'
    ).then(function() {
        console.log('Success');
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
};
```

Yes, I want to be a local file without having to download it, this is a show off app that won't have internet connection where will be running for just one day. So the files **have to be** local.

I have no idea how to open the file paths like in Android. Running on **iOS 9.3.3**., iPad Pro. Also, the device is not jail-broken.

**Edit:**
Well, now I'm trying to move the files from the app's folder to another one, so I can open it from there. Again, all of the code works on Android.

```
    function openPDF(uri) {         
    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/pdf/fichas/name.pdf';
    alert(filePath);        
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, function(entry) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var targetFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + entry.name;
        fileTransfer.download(
            entry.toURL(),
            targetFile,
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
                console.log("targetFile: " + targetFile);                   
                cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                    targetFile,
                    'application/pdf', 
                    {
                        error : function(error){ alert('open error ' + JSON.stringify(error)) }, 
                        success : function(){ } 
                    } 
                );

            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            }
        );  
        }, function(error){ alert('error resolveLocalFileSystemURI ' + JSON.stringify(error)) });
        };
```

- alert(filePath); * returns: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/NAME.app/www/pdf/name.pdf

I don't know where it fails though. I won't open anything.

**edit2:**
I get a FileTransfer error indeed. "

> Could not create path to save dowloaded file.

Comment: but you need to download file in IOS before open with file transfer plugin.

Comment: I've updated the main post.

Comment: debugg for IOS, file is there or not before open.

Comment: I added the error I'm getting.